# Graphitic acid-Its structure and properties?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

What exactly is graphitic acid? I know that it's obtained when you react graphite with concentrated $\ce{HNO3}$ and that its structural formula is $\ce{C11H4O5}$. But I can't find or deduce its structure. And also I am unable to find any of its properties, except that it's a yellow-green liquid insoluble in water.

Comment: $\ce{C4H11O5}$ is not a valid formula for any uncharged-non radical compound.  Perhaps this is the empirical formula?

Comment: Sorry it's C11H4O5

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphite_oxide

Answer (score 5):

Graphitic acid is a compound derived from graphite.

You may find it named "Graphite oxide" as well: as you see, it is obtained by reacting graphite with an oxidizing agent ($\ce{HNO3}$, for instance).

The structure resembles that of graphite, but it carries several oxygen-containing substituents, such as hydroxyl and carbonyl functions, thus having a less regular geometry, compared to that of graphite.

The exact features of the structure depend a lot on the method used for its preparation, and the layers may show some "defects", not described by this ideally planar model, but the key concept is this.

Here is a simple proposed structure for a single layer (source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphite_oxide#/media/File:Graphite_oxide.svg))

[image]

Note that, just like graphite is made of several layers of graphene, graphite oxide is made of several layers that, upon reaction with a base, become graphene oxide.

[Here you can find further information, and a nice image of a single graphene oxide film](http://www.azonano.com/article.aspx?ArticleID=4044)